# extra missing when I receive intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, missing-data

I was reading many posts here, but I can't find any similar problem or any similar solution to my problem.
I have a method that return 1 o 0 depends of the gender selected in a radiobutton `getcode`
It's works fine I test it. So, when I click one button in method `onClickListener` I create an intent and send it to a BroudcastReciver:

```
var intent=Intent(this,Receiver::java).apply{putExtra("x",getcode()}
var pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0)
alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.timeInMillis,pi)
```

And receive it in the Recieve class as fallow:

```
onRecieve(c:Context,i:Intent){
i.getIntExtra("x",0)
}
```

The problem is that I send 0 or 1 and I always receive the first send value. If I send 0 the first time, I always receive 0, even when the intent is putting 1(I checked it)

Comment: instead of passing 0 in last argument inside `getBroadcast` use one of the Flags from `PendingIntent` class like `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` .

Comment: What you recommend me? I don't understand what you want to said. Can you explain better?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

As [@ADM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4168607/adm) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538639/extra-missing-when-i-receive-intent/65540920#comment115873043_65538639) I change this line to:

```
var pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```